# Getting buttons to change background color when left mouse button is down and you hover over them

Tags: c#

I have a grid of buttons, can get the to change color when clicked rotating through 3 colors using

```
    private void button119_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "Aquamarine":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                break;
            case "CornflowerBlue":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                break;
        }
```

I just need them to do the same thing when i left mouse click and hover over them. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by click and hover? Do you want the button to keep changing colors while you hover over it and the mouse is pressed? What about adding a tag to the question indicating WPF or WinForms?

Comment: I suppose you ought to implement the MouseHover event as well.  Hard to see how it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MouseHover event and Control.MouseButtons static property.
I would do something like that:

```
private void button119_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeColor(sender as Control);
    }

private void button119_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.MouseButtons == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) 
        { 
            ChangeColor(sender as Control);
        }
    }

private void ChangeColor(Control ctrl)
    {
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
        case "Aquamarine":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        case "Yellow":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            break;
        case "CornflowerBlue":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            break;
        default:
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks that kind of helps. Being more specific i want to the buttons to change color when i click on them and when i hold the left mouse button and scroll over them they should change color once.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".forum").mouseover(function () {
            var colorOrig = $(".forum").css('background-color');
            if ($(".forum").css('background-color') == "rgb(127, 255, 212)") {

                $(".forum").css("background-color", "yellow");
            } else if ($(".forum").css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
                $(".forum").css("background-color", "CornflowerBlue");

            } else if ($(".forum").css('background-color') == "rgb(100, 149, 237)") {
                $(".forum").css("background-color", "Gainsboro");


            } else if ($(".forum").css('background-color') == "rgb(220, 220, 220)") {
                $(".forum").css("background-color", "Aquamarine");
            }
        });
```